# setCustomValidity no funciona

Tags: javascript

Hola buenas noches estoy tratando de modificar el mensaje default del atributo required con el setCustomValidity pero no me lo toma que podria ser...

HTML:

```
          <form name="info" method="GET" id="caja-form">
              <h1>CONTACTANOS</h1>

            <fieldset>
              <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" id="nombre" required>
            </fieldset>  

              <fieldset>
                <input type="email" name="mail" placeholder="Email" id="correo" required>
              </fieldset>

              <fieldset>
                <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Asunto" id="asunto" required>
              </fieldset>

              <fieldset>
                <textarea placeholder="Mensaje" name="msg"maxlength="140" rows="5" id="mensaje" required></textarea>
              </fieldset>

              <fieldset>
                <button name="submit"  type="submit" id="enviar" value="ingresar">ENVIAR</button>  
              </fieldset>

          </form>
```

JS:

```
   'use strict'

   window.addEventListener("load", function() {

       function checkImputs(){
           var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

           for(var i= 0; i<=inputs.length; i++){  

               if(inputs[i].value=='' && inputs[i] == validity.valueMissing && inputs[i] != validity.valid){
                   inputs[i].setCustomValidity("Todos los campos son obligatorios");                                        
               }else{
                   inputs[i].setCustomValidity("");

               }

           }   


       }  

       var enviar = document.querySelector("#enviar");
               enviar.addEventListener("click", function(){
               return checkImputs();

       });
   })
```

Cualquier ayuda o comentario de mejora sera Bienvenido!!

Muchas Gracias!!

Answer (score 3):

Tienes alguna cosa mal:

1.- El `for` tiene que ir hasta `i<inputs.length` porque si no vas a obtener un último valor `undefined` (recuerda que empiezas en 0)

2.- `validity` no es una variable, es una propiedad de tu objeto `inputs[i]`:

```
inputs[i].validity.valueMissing

!inputs[i].validity.valid
```

Te dejo aquí un ejemplo funcionando:

```js
'use strict'

   window.addEventListener("load", function() {

       function checkImputs(){
           let inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

           for(var i= 0; i<inputs.length; i++){  
               if(inputs[i].value=='' && inputs[i].validity.valueMissing && !inputs[i].validity.valid){                   inputs[i].setCustomValidity("Todos los campos son obligatorios"); 
               }else{
                   inputs[i].setCustomValidity("");
               }
           }   
       }  

       let enviar = document.querySelector("#enviar");
               enviar.addEventListener("click", function(){
               return checkImputs();
       });
   })
```

```html
<form name="info" method="GET" id="caja-form">
              <h1>CONTACTANOS</h1>

            <fieldset>
              <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" id="nombre" required>
            </fieldset>  

              <fieldset>
                <input type="email" name="mail" placeholder="Email" id="correo" required>
              </fieldset>

              <fieldset>
                <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Asunto" id="asunto" required>
              </fieldset>

              <fieldset>
                <textarea placeholder="Mensaje" name="msg"maxlength="140" rows="5" id="mensaje" required></textarea>
              </fieldset>

              <fieldset>
                <button name="submit"  type="submit" id="enviar" value="ingresar">ENVIAR</button>  
              </fieldset>

          </form>
```